# Create a bootable VMDK image

Tags: image, virtualbox, digital-ocean

We have a CentOS machine running on DigitalOcean. And now we would like to create a vmdk image of that machine which should be supported on VirtualBox.

Please see the below commands which we used to create vmdk image

1) created a raw image from the entire system using dd command

> dd if=/dev/vda of=disk.img , where vda is the volume.

2) then converted the raw image using vboxmanage command

> VBoxManage convertfromraw disk.img disk.vmdk --format VMDK

Then we downloaded the vmdk image, and tried to create a new VM on VirtualBox. But we were getting an error message as follows :

> FATAL: no bootable medium found! System Halted.

It would be great if anyone help us to create a bootable vmdk image from running centos machine.